# Using Invalid Pointers / Memory Addresses : C++ (windows)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I am trying to write a variable monitoring class that allows me to pass it a pointer (ideally void*) addressing a memory location which would normally be completely out-of-scope or inaccessible for the class. The class would then periodically display on the screen in text the contents of that memory location - interpreted in a user defined way (eg. (int*) ). I would only ever read from memory using this pointer and it would serve as a dirty hack to enable a kind of watch window during development for the variables that I am temporarily interested in monitoring during run-time - without introducing a lot of code to bring these variables in scope / accessible to the class.

I am using VC++ 2010 and it seems to flat out refuse to let me even write an out of scope memory location address to the pointer.

I guess there's a lot going on under the hood in windows such that this approach may have very limited applicability as memory locations change but I am using native C++ so am hoping that my addresses are persistent enough to be useful. Also, I can see that it would not like me accessing a memory location that my program is not actually using for security reasons...

Any ideas how I can do this? (I realise that using such pointers gives rise to undefined behaviour so would only ever read from them and display the value).

Thanks.

Comment: In what way does VC++ refuse to let you do this? I.e., what have you tried so far? You should be able to just say "void * x = (void *) 12345;"

Comment: If your goal is to watch your own variables, why are you trying to access memory that you aren't using? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Daniel, I am using it - but for example it might be an address on the stack, or a deleted heap address. The way I am using it - I don't expect it to disappear but in theory it could...

Comment: Ernest - I'll work up a simplified example....

Comment: Ernest - Interestingly on a simplified example in a new project it worked fine - but not in the mix of a larger complicated application - more complex memory allocations going on below the surface I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to dereference pointers that point outside any space which you can account for is pretty much meaningless. The address you may be accessing might not even be mapped into the memory space of your process so there is actually nothing even to look at.
When your process starts, You don't actually have 4 GB at your disposal. the memory space size is 4 GB but it is mostly made of holes that are not mapped to your process.

Eventually it all comes down to where you got the pointer you're trying to use. Memory addresses which you usually *can* account for may come from:

- heap allocations - anything inside the ranges allocated by `malloc` or `new` and not yet `free`d or `deleted`
- stack space, global variables - anything you define as variables in your program inside the scopes of your current position in the program. Accessing anything defined in other scopes is meaningless (for instance, returning a pointer to a local variable from a function)
- code segments - addresses inside the segments of memory that contain the DLL or EXE of your process that were not unloaded. Usually you can access them only for read-only access. You can find such addresses for instance by looking up the return address of a function.

Accessing a pointer in a memory chunk you just deallocated is exactly a case of such meaninglessness. Once you deallocated your memory, there is a certain chance that it was already returned to the OS and that that address is no longer mapped to your process.

You can further read about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Comment: Thanks for this - I was hoping that it would be slightly less meaningless than it turned out to be... I'll have to do it the hard way...